# How do you add httplib2 into ansible?

Tags: python, pip, ansible

I am trying to use the [get_url](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/get_url_module.html) module for ansible and when I run it I get the following error:

```
failed: [localhost] => (item=10) => {"failed": true, "item": "10"}
msg: httplib2 is not installed
```

Now I have successfully installed httplib2 using pip:

```
pip install httplib2
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): httplib2 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
```

But obviously that hasn't helped the situation.  I can see that ansible is using a different PYTHON_PATH than the OS (where httplib2 is installed) but I cannot work out how to get a httplib2 installed into that path (other than copying it which isn't nice).

Any help greatly appreciate.

Comment: Why don't you just use ftplib?

Comment: I got around this issue by writing a python module and calling that.  I couldn't get it to natively work in python.  I suspect it was a clash with python libraries but I couldn't work it out.

Answer (score 3):

If this is an ansible-playbook error, you can run a pip command to install the httplib2 artifact. Try running the following task before:

```
      tasks:
        - name: pip httplib2
          # ansible uri module requires httplib2
          pip: name=httplib2 extra_args="--user"
```

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this problem on one of my Macs (I had been switching between a Homebrew Python installation and the system install recently, so something was funky anyways), and what ended up fixing it, at least for a particular session, was  starting an interactive python session on the CLI and importing the library:

```
$ python
>>> import httplib2
>>> exit()
$ [continue what you were doing with ansible...]
```

Answer (score 0):

- Find out how did you install Ansible and where is the Python installation Ansible is using. Explorer your hard disk with your file manager.
- Use `pip` command from this particular Python installation (usually in `bin` directory) to install `httplib2`. This way httplib2 ends up to the right Python installation.

Furthermore to find out what Python command Ansible is using do:

```
 which ansible
```

Shows you full path to the ansible executable. And then:

```
 head /where/is/my/ansible/command
```

It prints you the script header which should include full path to `python` command.

Comment: I have already used pip to install httplib2 and ansible is using the OS copy of python.  It does seem to be using a different PYTHONPATH but I can't work out how to get ansible to pick that up.

Comment: which ansible
/usr/local/bin/ansible

Comment: cat /usr/local/bin/ansible
#!/bin/bash
PYTHONPATH="/usr/local/Cellar/ansible/1.9.1/libexec/lib/python2.7/site-packages:/usr/local/Cellar/ansible/1.9.1/libexec/vendor/lib/python2.7/site-packages:/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages" exec "/usr/local/Cellar/ansible/1.9.1/libexec/bin/ansible" "$@"

Comment: That calls a script that is using /usr/bin/python, which is the OS default.

Comment: Does it work when do `python` and then do `import httplib2`?

Comment: `/usr/local/Cellar/` is Homebrew Python installation path, not the system-wide Python installation path, so something is off here